# How to accept only 5 inputs using recursion and if loops?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a recursive function using only `if` statements and recursion that will accept at most 5 inputs. If more than 5 inputs are received, the function returns `None`. The code I have so far is:

```py
def foo()
  count = 0
  n = int(input())
  if n == 5:
    return n
  elif count != 5:
      count += 1
      return foo()
  else:
    return None
```

I understand that in each recursive call, count gets reset to 0 and hence, the program runs indefinitely. I just can't figure out how to modify it so that I can accept at most 5 inputs using only `if` statements and recursion.

**Edit:**
Global variables are not allowed. The function must not take in any parameters. The function can only make use of strings or mathematical techniques from the `math` module.

Comment: Pass the number of attempts in as an argument to the function?

Comment: Sorry but the function has to take no input, should have mentioned that

Comment: Then define a variable at a higher scope and use that (though, an input is better styling)

Comment: What exactly is this function supposed to do? Right now, it seems to return the number 5 if entered (it can't be, since `n` is always a string and never equal to the integer 5) or `None` after 5 tries? Recursion is never a good solution to a problem that can trivially be handled by a loop.

Comment: @Warlax56 I attempted that but global variables are not allowed for this program. I'll reflect that in the post now

Comment: @chepner hi, sorry I forgot to typecast the input. The function returns 5 if 5 is entered or None if 5 tries are attempted and failed. You're right that recursion is pretty inefficient for this but that's was the problem specifies

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark specified by the assignment, it would be a bad solution but I'm restricted in what techniques I can use

Comment: Are you allowed to use a (possibly nested) helper function that takes arguments?

Comment: @NielsWouda. I'm allowed to use a helper function but not local functions

Comment: @trinity Can the helper method take in parameters? If so, you can just make `foo` around a function with a parameter.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark yes helper functions can be used but none with default parameters. I'm tying to work up a solution for it without that now though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should suit your needs. It uses a helper method that takes in the number of inputs that you have remaining. `foo()` itself takes in no parameters.

This meets all of the following constraints described by OP in the comments:

- uses recursion
- uses a function that takes in no parameters
- no global variables
- no imports (`math` is allowed, but we don't need it here)
- returns `None` if 5 is not received within 5 tries, else returns 5.

```py
def get_input(inputs_remaining):
    if inputs_remaining <= 0:
        return None

    result = int(input())
    if result == 5:
        return 5

    return get_input(inputs_remaining - 1)


def foo():
    return get_input(5)

foo()
```

Comment: That works!! Thank you for your assistance and I apologize for not including all the information in the original post. Sorry for any confusion caused.

Comment: No worries. In the future, do try to include these sorts of things upfront, as these constraints are often artificial and eliminate solutions that most people would normally see as reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
def foo(count=5):
    if count == 1:
        return [input()]
    else:
        return [input()]+foo(count-1)
```

This will output a list with the n inputs

Comment: Hi, sorry I was just updating a list of restrictions for the problem, lists are not permitted. Furthermore, the function is not allowed to take in any variables or default parameters

Comment: @trinity what should be the output?

Comment: the output will be integer 5 if 5 is received by the user or None if 5 failed attempts are made to input 5